# using web role and worker role

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-phone, cloud

i am totally new for windows azure  and i am going through its features there are lot of options so i got confused. an app that is going to be made for both windows phone and windows 8.it will use images that is going to be store in cloud and user can download and upload images to cloud  and user can edit or like that image on the basis that i wanted to use push notifications.so my question is how proceed for it shoud i use webrole or worker role or something else. if i have to use webrole or  worker role plz explain it why because in push notification sample there nothing like web role or worker role mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of web/worker role, do take a look at Windows Azure Mobile Service - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/mobile/. You can use this to send push notifications across various mobile platforms (and not just Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8).

For storing images, take a look at Windows Azure Blob Storage.

**Update**

What you could do is store the images in Windows Azure Blob Storage and have a database to store image likes and stuff. Your application can query the database to get the list of images and likes etc. Anytime somebody likes an image, you just update the record in the database. To learn more about mobile services, I suggest you take a look at the tutorials listed on this page: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/.

Comment: ok gaurav, please tell can i apply logic on data available in tables or blob, like which user have how many likes(logic) and depending on that i can send notifications if yes then where i have to write this code..

Comment: Sounds like you're asking basic how-to questions in relation to interacting with storage services. That's a pretty broad bit of info. Perhaps it would be a good idea to start with the [Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) and walking through some of the exercises to get familiarized with mobile services?